# RBENV managed Rubies: VIM upgrade forcing homebrew to install Ruby

Tags: homebrew, vi, ruby, macos

I've recently switched from RVM to RBENV as my Ruby manager under MacOS Sierra.

```
$ rbenv version
2.3.1 (set by /Users/meltemi/.rbenv/version)
$ which ruby
/Users/meltemi/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

I've used Homebrew to install packages like `vim` for years and never had Ruby version be installed via Homebrew.

Now when I `brew upgrade vim` I get a forced dependency install of Ruby.

```
==> Upgrading vim
==> Installing dependencies for vim: ruby
==> Installing vim dependency: ruby
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ruby-2.3.1_2.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring ruby-2.3.1_2.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/rake
Target /usr/local/bin/rake
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/rake'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite ruby

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run ruby

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/rake
/usr/local/bin/rdoc
/usr/local/bin/ri
==> Caveats
Emacs Lisp files have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/ruby
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_2: 1,261 files, 18.8M
```

How can I get Homebrew (read: `vim`) to use the `rbenv` version of Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby is a dependency for building `vim` with Homebrew according to the package details:

```
ianc.local
> brew info vim
vim: stable 8.0.0019 (bottled), HEAD
Vi "workalike" with many additional features
http://www.vim.org/
Conflicts with: ex-vi
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/vim.rb
==> Dependencies
Optional: lua ✘, luajit ✘
==> Requirements
Required: ruby >= 1.8 ✔, perl >= 5.3 ✔
Recommended: python ✔
Optional: python3 ✔
==> Options
--with-client-server
    Enable client/server mode
--with-custom-perl
    Build with a custom Perl instead of the Homebrew version.
--with-custom-python
    Build with a custom Python 2 instead of the Homebrew version.
--with-custom-ruby
    Build with a custom Ruby instead of the Homebrew version.
--with-lua
    Build vim with lua support
--with-luajit
    Build with luajit support
--with-mzscheme
    Build vim with mzscheme support
--with-override-system-vi
    Override system vi
--with-python3
    Build vim with python3 instead of python[2] support
--with-tcl
    Build vim with tcl support
--without-nls
    Build vim without National Language Support (translated messages, keymaps)
--without-perl
    Build vim without perl support
--without-python
    Build vim without python support
--without-ruby
    Build vim without ruby support
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

But as you can see, it only requires `ruby 1.8`. It's installing a ruby because `rbenv` likely isn't returning an installed ruby when the `ruby` shim is called by the build package.

Given `vim` will dynamically link to your Ruby installation, I highly recommend you just switch to system ruby before you brew install or upgrade vim. Something like:

```
brew uninstall vim ruby
brew cleanup
rbenv global system
brew install --build-from-source vim --with-custom-ruby
```

The installer will happily use system ruby on the Mac, which has a high enough version, during installation and the resulting binaries created won't segfault if you happen to remove the specific ruby version they were built against, which is a real problem if you use a rbenv-controlled ruby at build time.

Alternatively you can build without ruby support:

```
brew install vim --without-ruby
```

But that's probably not what you want.

Comment: `$ rbenv system`… `rbenv: no such command 'system'`. Me thinks `system` is a substitute for version #.  So how easily to switch to system Ruby *and* then back again to whatever was set before?

Comment: Do you have a `~/.rbenv/version`? Try `rbenv global system`.

Comment: ok, tried that. still not working. still insists on installing homebrew's Ruby.

Comment: This worked: `brew uninstall vim ruby` and then `rbenv global system ` and then `brew install vim --with-custom-ruby` and that seems to compile with system ruby.

Comment: This worked for me with one exception. I was getting `if_python.c:67:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found` after these docs. The command that worked in the end for me was `brew install vim --with-custom-ruby --without-python`

Comment: This no longer works with `vim: stable 8.1.0450 (bottled)` on Mojave. No longer the option `--with-custom-ruby`.

Comment: @Meltemi `(bottled)` means it's pre-compiled binary. Try using `--build-from-source` to have it build from source instead of downloading a pre-built binary. I've updated the answer to include that option.

Comment: @IanC. Took your advice to `--build-from-source` and now `Warning: vim: this formula has no --with-custom-ruby option so it will be ignored!`… `ld: library not found for -lruby.2.5.1` and 
`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

Comment: @Meltemi `brew info vim` is telling me the vim formula now has a hard dependency (required) on ruby. You'll need to `brew install ruby` if you want to get it via homebrew now.

Comment: You can read about how these additional options are no longer allowed here https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/22596.